# E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.example.YPLContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm recieving such a message in logs of my Android application.

> E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for
>   com.example.myapp.YPLContentProvider

I searched, but did not find any reference for YPLContentProvider. I'm not using   or implementing such a class in my code.

Also there is

> E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for
>   com.example.myapp.MetrikaContentProvider

What is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not logs from your application.
It seems that you have some Yandex android apps installed on you device (like Yandex.Maps) which have component seeking for metrics provider for every app in your device (unwanted behaviour but it works so), including app you developed.

```
 01-25 15:23:15.745 22000-22044/ru.yandex.yandexmaps E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.vhqlabs.TextPoll.YPLContentProvider
```

Comment: @constpetrov You should remove all Yandex applications to solve this.